# Один и тот же метод во многих Activity

Tags: java, android

Недавно начал изучение java и android и решил написать приложение. Есть некий метод `loadData(List<Item> itemList);`, который на вход принимает коллекцию. Этот метод используется в нескольких `activity`. Чтобы в каждом активити не писать повторно этот метод, можно ли создать отдельный статический класс и в нем написать данный метод, а в активити его вызывать так `MyStaticClass.loadData(List<Item> itemList);`? Не возникнет ли случаев краха приложения?

Answer (score 4):

> Чтобы в каждом активити не писать повторно этот метод, можно ли создать отдельный статический класс и в нем написать данный метод, а в активити его вызывать так `MyStaticClass.loadData(List<Item> itemList);`?

*(не статический класс, а статический метод!)*

Чисто технически, если метод не использует поля класса активити, то можно, но стоит это делать лишь в том случае, если метод *утилитный* (да и вообще, кидаться вьюхами куда-либо не очень хорошая идея).

Судя по контексту вопроса, Ваш метод привязан к активити, поэтому здесь лучше определить базовый класс с этим методом, а другие активити, где нужен данный метод, отнаследовать от него.

Comment: Решение с наследованием хорошее, но ведь в java не поддерживается множественное наследование. А класс Activity по умолчанию при создании активити наследуется от AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Скорпион, Отнаследуйте базовую активити от `AppCompatActivity`, делов-то.

Comment: да, логично) не подумал сразу

Answer (score 0):

Краха приложения не произойдет при вызове метода из другого класса. Создайте класс, например, MyHelper. В нем создайте свой метод, определите в нем логику и вызывайте его из любого места вашего приложения.

```
public MyHelper{

     public static void mymethod(List<Item> somelist){
     //some logic
     }
}
```

Comment: А можно ли объявить данный класс статическим, чтобы не создавая экземпляр класса вызывать метод? Если нельзя то почему?

Comment: Можно, только нужно помнить, что статические члены класса напрямую принадлежат классу, а не его экземпляру. То есть, если у вас есть какие-либо свойства внутри класса(переменные), то значение статических переменных будет одинаковым для всех объектов типа MyHelper

Comment: Да, я помню.. В нужном мне методе используется кастомный адаптер MyItemAdapter для RecyclerView, а также сам RecyclerView.. Если класс сделать статическим и передать на вход методу эти параметры правильно будет?

Comment: Все зависит от логики вашего приложения, если члены класса вам не нужны, а только методы, то пользуйтесь. Помните, что статические поля и методы не потокобезопасны (Thread-safe) в Javа, что может привести к проблемам с безопасностью в вашем приложении.

Comment: понял. Спасибо.